# Set Cell to a number of lines in a GridView c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a GridView in asp.net (c#) that is bound to a EntityDataSource

I want to set one column of text to be 3 lines (height) and than fit in the width .

I have played a bit with it but with no success 
here is the code itself

```
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Height="20px" />
                            <ItemStyle Height="50px" Width="150px" Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

btw there is no special need for me for it to be as a template field...

Anyone has an idea ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Isn't this simply a case of setting the Label and TextBox Height?

Comment: no it wont work right... the text will not adjust it width automatically

Answer (score 1):

The ItemStyle would be applied to the cell; try applying the size to the label and textbox too.  Also, wouldn't you want the Wrap property to be set to True so content would wrap and you'd get the content within 3 lines?

Comment: if i set it to true and the height of the itemstyle and the label to lets say 40px the widht will not fit itself and the text will overflow to the bottom..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TextBox you can use or a .NET server control:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
```

Or you can use a client tag, with the runat = "server"

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server"></textarea>
```

With this tips you can take it like a textbox on three rows.

Comment: i need the label to be 3 lines and not a textbox